# Grabbing image google search results

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am attempting to grab a Google image off the first page of results of a Google search without knowing the search beforehand. I have tried the recommended Google JavaScript code to try to grab the image but the response I am getting is:

> "unexpected <".

Does anyone know why this would be and how I would combat this response?

I filled in the following code with my API key and cx (which I'm not gonna display publicly for obvious reasons):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Search JSON API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // Make sure HTML in item.htmlTitle is escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").append(
          document.createElement("br"),
          document.createTextNode(item.htmlTitle)
        );
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned the resulting message was:

> "unexpected <"